# Why can I not import a function name within a data structure

Tags: python, function, python-import, nameerror

I have a function and a dictionary containing a reference to that function.

```
def func1(): print('blah')

dict1 = {'func1': func1}
```

If I paste these into the python interpreter in the order given, all works well.

```
`>>> def func1(): print('blah')
... 

>>> func1
<function func1 at 0x7f8939d77730>

>>> func1()
blah

>>> dict1 = {'func1': func1}
>>> dict1['func1']()
blah

`
```

But if I import `dict1` from a file, the interpreter says `func1` is not defined, even though it is defined.

So, with file 'dictfile.py' containing a single line of text:

```
dict1 = {'func1': func1}
```

Then this into the interpreter:

```
>>> def func1(): print('blah')
... 
>>> func1()
blah

>>> from dictfile import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/../dictfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    dict1 = {'func1': func1}
NameError: name 'func1' is not defined
>>>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: func1 reference exists at run time, you cant save or load it from file.

Comment: use something like `getattr(module, func1)` where you are assigning value to dict.

Comment: Raghava's comment is useful and informative, and sounds like an answer. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: This website is a bit hokey: people are always deleting their comments when one of your replies makes them change their mind about what they said.

Comment: Are you getting `NameError` on importing a module that contains exactly those two lines? That shouldn't happen, since the name `func1` should be in scope when `dict1` is initialized. Have you verified that this error occurs with *only* those lines in the respective files?

Comment: @Raghava: That doesn't make any sense. `import` loads function objects from files all the time.

Comment: I've added further clarification in response to your helpful expressions of bafflement.

Comment: Now that's more helpful, thank you.

Comment: You want a separate module to be able to access the variables defined in "main" module that is used by the REPL?

Comment: @DanielPryden yes, import loads the function objects from files. but here, function is in different scope and only dict1 is imported from file hence my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func1` is not defined in the scope of your `dictfile.py` context.

The global scope of 'func1' is limited to that it defines itself. This is so it can operate as a self-contained module. That is, so it can operate as a module is supposed to operate: so it can be imported and run by any other module. This is done to avoid clashes when different modules use identical names for different things in their global definitions.

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module
>   without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global
>   variables.

By loading the file with an import statement you make it a module. You cannot then expect that module to acquire the scope from which you import it. It's own scope remains distinct. Its integrity is protected. It must itself import any definitions it uses if it does not define them itself.

For you to be able to load the dictionary which references the function, the function has to be defined in the scope (the file) in which it is located.

Since the `dictfile.py` file doesn't know anything about your interpreter's current state (your state isn't imported into the file and I'm not sure if that's possible), it can't find the reference to the function.

According to the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules),

> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the
>   global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the
>   author of a module can use global variables in the module without
>   worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables. On
>   the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a
>   module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its
>   functions, modname.itemname.

For your function to be accessible in your module's (file's) scope, you'd need to import your interactive interpreter's "module", which I don't think is possible.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, that does appear to be the case. But why is this so? It seems counter intuitive. I have in my scope the function defined. I then call into that scope a declaration that contains within it a reference to that function. Since I am bringing that declaration into my scope, am I not making the declaration in a scope that contains the object to which it refers? The delcaration is surely not made in the dumb file. It is made when I import the file, and when I import the file the function it needs is defined in my scope.

Comment: @markling see updated answer; added a few more details I found on the Python docs which should help explain it.

Comment: Thank you, @Pedro-von-Hertwig. I have edited your answer to elaborate that part of it I felt most instructive in helping me understand the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Each module defines a namespace, so "global" variables in a module are actually scoped to that module; another module can access them, but it needs to do so through the module that defined the name.

When running in an interactive session, objects you create are added to a special module called `__main__`. Another module *could* import things from this if it wanted, but I don't recommend it.

As an example for learning purposes only:

```
$ cat dictfile.py
from __main__ import func1
dict1 = {'func1': func1}

$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def func1(): print('blah')
...
>>> from dictfile import dict1
>>> dict1
{'func1': <function func1 at 0x102735c08>}
>>> dict1['func1']()
blah
```

In a real-world program, you should avoid circular dependencies like this. But it still can be useful to import functions from one module, assemble them into a data structure in another module, and then use the data structure from a third module.

A good rule of thumb about dependencies between parts of your program: implementations should only depend on abstractions, and abstractions should only depend on other abstractions.

Comment: Yes, this cicular dependency is precisely what I have created, and will be ditching immediately, with questions now put aside for future consideration on what must be done instead to achieve the same ends by different means. Thank you.